# how to speed up the uploading of files

Tags: java, file-upload

Here I am trying to make an uploader in java spring where user is going to upload large files (around up to 200 mb) so can any one advise here to speed up the writing process of that file on server. Following is the code I am using to write the file on server.

```
if (!file.isEmpty()) {
    byte[] bytes = file.getBytes() ;                    
    BufferedOutputStream bufferedOutputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(
        new FileOutputStream(new File("/home/" + file.originalName())));
    bufferedOutputStream.write(bytes);
    bufferedOutputStream.close() ;                    
} else {
    System.out.println("file is empty");
}
```

Comment: Speed depends on lot of factors Client's net speed, server's net speed etc, it would be difficult to answer in a single answer.

Comment: i am asking if we could enhance speed by writing good piece of code and also am i doing the writing of file in a best way or not.

Comment: You could use `Files.copy()` for starters (provided you use Java 7)

Comment: i am not using java 7

Comment: Are the files compressable? Then GZipOutputStream/GZipInputStream would help.

Comment: @JoopEggen : i have to upload .xlsx file in original format on server, can not upload file in compressed format.

Comment: Well you can SUPPORT the uploading of zipped files and let the application unpack them if the user applies that trick. Other than that performance improvements will be in the hardware.

Comment: xlsx can be both a pure XML or a zip file with XML files inside. Check that it indeed is a zip file. Of course with the zip format, compression is moot. (Web servers often know how to handle compressed transfer, with a Deflate header parameter at the client, generally used by the browser.)

Comment: Thank you guys, this indeed will help my process.

Comment: You're far more likely to be spending most of the time in the upload than in writing it to a local file.

Comment: @EJP : i did not get your point.